# Trying to create a hash table in JS... Can't figure out how to write a "get" function with the given hash function without being given an index

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, hashtable, hashcode

So I have been able to create a set function that seems to work correctly. The problem comes when I try to create a 'get' function that searches the hashtable passed on a 'key' passed in as an argument.

The hashing function takes a 'string' and 'size' argument, not a 'key' like all the examples I looked at trying to figure it out. Here is the hashing function I was given...

```
  function hashCode(string, size){
    let hash = 0;
    if (string.length == 0) return hash;
    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
      const letter = string.charCodeAt(i);
      hash = ((hash << 5) - hash) + letter;
      hash = hash & hash; // Convert to 32bit integer
    }
    return Math.abs(hash) % size ;
  }
```

Here is my 'set' 'HashTable' class function andthe 'set' function I wrote...

```
function HashTable() {
    this.SIZE = 16;
    this.storage = new Array(this.SIZE);
  }
  
  // stores a value in the storage array
  HashTable.prototype.set = function(key, value) {
    let index = hashCode(value, 16);
    if (!this.storage[index]) {
      this.storage[index] = [];
    }
    this.storage[index][key] = value
  };
```

I have tried a few different methods to make the 'get' function work. I have tried iterating through the array and using the .hasOwnProperty method and currently tried to just use dot notation in a loop to find the property (what is shown below). I can't seem to get it to work with the methods I listed and can't think of any other ways to find the key/value pair in the array without being able to get an index from the hashing function.

Here is the 'get' method I am working on...

```
HashTable.prototype.get = function(key) {
    this.storage.forEach((kvpair) => {
        if (kvpair.key) {
            return kvpair.key
        }
    })
  };
```

when I create a new instance of the class like this...

```
 let table = new HashTable;
```

and run the 'set' function...

```
table.set('key','value');
```

and console.log 'table' I get this...

```
HashTable {SIZE: 16, storage: [ , [ key: 'value' ], , , , , , , , , , , , , , ] }
```

when I attempt to run my 'get' method...

```
table.get('key')
```

undefined is logged to the console...

I am just unsure of how to make this 'get' function work without the index... I am obviously not retrieving the value correctly with my loop and dot notation...

Any tips, tricks, ideas, hints, or help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should consider marking good answers as accepted. I see in your history you hardly ever do that. Any reason why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I slightly changed your get function:

```
HashTable.prototype.get = function(key) {    
    var value = null
    this.storage.forEach((kvpair) => {
            if (kvpair.key) {
              value = kvpair.key;
            }
        })
    return value;
    };
```

I have no idea why this works and your code does not...

If anyone can explain why, thank you.

Comment: Me either! But thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `get` method doesn't have a `return` statement. True, the callback that is passed to `forEach` has a `return` statement, but that defines the return value of the callback, not of the `get` method.

Moreover, returning a value inside a `forEach` callback is useless: that returned value is going nowhere. `forEach` does not do anything with it.

Instead I would suggest using `find`:

```
HashTable.prototype.get = function(key) {
    return this.storage.find(kvpair => kvpair.key)?.key;
};
```

This will also iterate over the key/value pairs, but `find` is designed to stop the iteration as soon as the callback returns a truthy value. Since you want `key` to be truthy, it is enough to return `kvpair.key` inside that callback. Then `find` will return the `kvpair` for which this `key` is truthy. It then remains to grab again the `key` property.

The `?.` operator will make sure that if the key is not found, and `find` will return `undefined`, that no error will occur, but that `undefined` will be returned instead of accessing a property on `undefined`.

Comment: Super answer, thanks a lot for this clarification!